# Base URL is not working in Grails production mode

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails-2.4.5 version. I have some menu link in my side menu template where I am using attribute for controller name and action.

And in my application.js file calling URL with that attribute. It is working fine in development mode and displaying every page fine. But
when I run war, if I click the link it only append the # sign in the URL but no page displaying.

My menu link:

```
...
<li>
    <a class="action-item" controller="designation" action="index" href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i> Designation</a>
</li>
...
```

My JS function to render the page:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.action-item").on("click", function (e) {
        var controller = $(this).attr("controller");
        var action = $(this).attr("action");
        var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8090/madrasa/";

        $("#spinnerDiv").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + controller + "/" + action,
            data: {
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#page-wrapper').html(data);
                $("#spinnerDiv").hide();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                if (xhr.status == 403) {
                    showForbiddenModal("Sorry, You are not authorized for this action");
                    $("#spinnerDiv").hide();
                    return false;
                }
                console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                $("#spinnerDiv").hide();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

Comment: `var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8090/madrasa/";` it's a dev address. distinguish environments

Comment: @Michal_Szulc how to overcome the issue

Comment: Let grails build the url for you...  use `<g:link action="..." controller="...">` and the anchor tab will be built with the full URL, you can then extract that via `$(this).attr("href")`.  However, your problem seems to be that there's an error somewhere in the JavaScript which is keeping the `e.preventDefault()` from triggering (hence, you're ending up at the designated `#`) location.  Check your JavaScript console to find that.